# Define memoized getter dynamically in ruby

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

Using Ruby, I want to dynamically create class-level instance variables inside corresponding getters. For two of them, I use attr_reader. But for those which need to be initialized to an empty array, I do the following:

```
class MatchMake
  class << self
    attr_reader :local_data, :remote_data
    ["type1", "type2"].each do |elem|
      define_method "#{elem}_matches".to_sym do
        instance_variable_set("@#{elem}_matches", [])
      end
    end
  end
  ...
end
```

from my understanding this code is equivalent to:

```
class MatchMake
  class << self
    def local_data
      @local_data
    end
    def remote_data
      @remote_data
    end
    def type1_matches
      @type1_matches = []
    end
    def type2_matches
      @type2_matches = []
    end
  end
  ...
end
```

Firstly I would like to know if I am correct in my understanding. Secondly, I would like to know if there is a way to memoize the variables, as in the following:

```
def type1_matches
  @type1_matches ||= []
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you define `type1_matches`, not `type1`. Secondly, `define_method` accepts strings, `#to_sym` is superfluous. The last, but not least, you define getter being in fact a setter. So, to define `type1` as you wanted:

```
define_method "#{elem}=", value do
  instance_variable_set("@#{elem}", value)
end
```

Now, for getter, lazily instantiated to empty array:

```
define_method "#{elem}" do
  instance_variable_set("@#{elem}", []) \
      unless instance_variable_defined?("@#{elem}")
  instance_variable_get("@#{elem}")
end
```

Comment: My mistake, my code should read def type1_matches, gonna edit the question to reflect above.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a sample pattern that I wrote for such use-cases:
https://gist.github.com/ritikesh/09384fec25c4b05cfdec8674ce3a9076

here's the code from it:

```
# memoize db/cache results in instance variable dynamically
def memoize_results(key)
  return instance_variable_get(key) if instance_variable_defined?(key)
  instance_variable_set key, yield  
end

# usage
MY_CONSTANT = [:active, :inactive]
MY_CONSTANT.each { |key|
  define_method("#{key}_users") do
    memoize_results("@#{key}_users") do
      User.send(key).all # assumes that user responds to active, inactive(via scope/filter etc..)
    end
  end
}
```

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)